# How do I set up an Exchange Account in Mac Mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, ms-office

I am having trouble transferring my account settings from Entourage to Mac Mail.  **Specifically, what is the equivalent setting in Mac Mail for the Domain setting in Entourage?**

In Entourage I have the following account settings.

```
PERSONAL INFORMATION
  Name: My Name
  E-mail Address: me@mycompany.org

AUTHENTICATION
  Account ID: myUserName
  Domain: NETBSA

SERVER INFORMATION
  Exchange Server: https://path.to.webmail
  [x] This DAV Service requires a secure connection
```

I can see in Mac Mail where all the other settings match up when creating a new account, but I'm not sure what "Domain" means or where I can specify it in Mac Mail. Is it some quirky Microsoft thing that only Exchange supports?

Whenever I try to set up my account in Mac Mail the server just times out.

Answer (score 3):

Domain shuld be the beginning part of your username when you logon to your machine or account at work.  It's the name of your internal corporate network.  It looks like this when you sign on to machines at work:

```
netbsa\myusername
```

You might need to specify this format as your username in mail.app.  However, if it's timing out, it's probably more likely that the server settings are wrong.  Don't use the https:// part in the server settings and see if it will connect.